# Selenium grid manipulation software

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm running selenium grid as described [here](http://www.code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2). 

I have the hub, and one node running on one virtual machine and the other nodes running on other virtual machines. 
When I go to `http://hub:4444/grid/`console I can see the nodes, and the configuration, but at many times I need to:

- Restart the whole grid
- Restart a node
- Add a node
- Remove a node

At the moment I do this by logging to all nodes and restarting/changing by hand. This is very time consuming, especcialy when I need to restart the whole grid.

My question is, is there a software where I define the machines, and I'm quickly able to make these changes. Something like a grid manipulation/configuration software or maybe some best practices that save time in these scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You could do research on, and maybe make an investment in the Amazon AWS.

If your selenium hub port (4444) is open to the public, you are able to use the AWS API to fire up instances which have a startup batch file to use your host when it starts up. `java -jar server.jar -role node -hub http:hub:4444/grid/register`

This also allows you to pretty much fire up X amount of instances, say 1000, each machine to run 1 test apiece. Potentially you could run an entire automated regression suite within an hour.

When you get a solid system in place, you can then, via command line (or via running your tests) fire up, then shut down instances on a whim, without any configuration.

**Selenium / Amazon**
[Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)
[Setting up your Grid](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_grid_as_infrastructural_tool.htm)

**Additional Material**
[Selenium Grid EC2 AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/selenium-grid)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a free solution. Another draw back is that not all apps I'm testing can be accessed from public> Also with this solution I would still end up manually managing the grid.

Comment: Not quite.   You are correct about it being a paid solution, however the Amazon VPC allows you to have your own cloud of instances, meaning that they have access to otherwise hidden web applications.  And no, you wouldn't manually manage it anymore after initial configuration.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem an year ago. I had asked somewhat similar question in SO earlier. [How to maintain Selenium Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250268/how-to-maintain-selenium-grid). Selenium Grid 2.0 provides some ways to integrate these features.

However, my organisation implemented something different. We created some UI screens for grid maintenance. Steps were like:

1. Get all the IP address and DNS of VMs in a database table
2. Create the mapping between Hub and RC VMs
3. Put a small java program in the startup of all VMs which will do a look up on DB to find out what hub it should connect to and what browser config should it use for the connection.
4. Create UI for reassigning the VMs between Hubs. Any assignment from UI will restart the VM and would in turn trigger the startup script.

It would take some time and effort for building the above solution but would be worth is what I feel after using for an year.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Grid is your test infrastructure, but it sounds like you need a layer above it to manage this infrastructure.

I recommend using Docker to manage your grid. There are some huge benefits to using Docker over the traditional VM setup:

1. Docker containers are more lightweight than VM's. There's less overhead per node to worry about.
2. Docker has many built in ways for quickly creating a grid, scaling your nodes up or down, and quickly restarting the whole grid.
3. Docker containers can all run on a single machine, so there's a central point of control. No more accessing each VM separately to troubleshoot or performance maintenance.

If you want to see an example, I did this recently at my company, and wrote about it here:

http://www.conductor.com/nightlight/running-selenium-grid-using-docker-compose/